# https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1 is working in local but not working in production

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

The URL [https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/?__a=1) is returning Json data correctly when i tried it in local machine but the same is returning a HTML login page when accessing it from AWS server. Can someone help me with this?

I have tried hosting it in Heroku as well. But of no use. Please note that the i was not logged in to instragram when i tried the same in my local machine

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I bet Instagram filter IP addresses from Heroku, AWS, GCP, etc... to prevent external sources to make huge queries and crawling. That draw ressources from their servers.